# Correlation coefficient of two columns in pandas dataframe with .corr()

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I would like to calculate the correlation coefficient between two columns of a pandas data frame after making a column boolean in nature. The original `table` had two columns: a `Group` Column with one of two treatment groups, now boolean, and an `Age` Group. Those are the two columns I'm looking to calculate the correlation coefficient.

I tried the `.corr()` method, with:

```
table.corr(method='pearson')
```

but have this returned to me:
[image]

I have pasted the first 25 rows of boolean `table` below. I don't know if I'm missing parameters, or how to interpret this result. It's also strange that it's 1 as well. Thanks in advance!

```
    Group  Age
0      1   50
1      1   59
2      1   22
3      1   48
4      1   53
5      1   48
6      1   29
7      1   44
8      1   28
9      1   42
10     1   35
11     0   54
12     0   43
13     1   50
14     1   62
15     0   64
16     0   39
17     1   40
18     1   59
19     1   46
20     0   56
21     1   21
22     1   45
23     0   41
24     1   46
25     0   35
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Calling `.corr()` on the entire DataFrame gives you a full correlation matrix:

```
>>> table.corr()
        Group     Age
Group  1.0000 -0.1533
Age   -0.1533  1.0000
```

You can use the separate Series instead:

```
>>> table['Group'].corr(table['Age'])
-0.15330486289034567
```

This should be faster than using the full matrix and indexing it (with `df.corr().iat['Group', 'Age']`).  Also, this should work whether `Group` is bool or int dtype.

Answer (score -1):

my data frame consists of many columns. the correlation between any 2 colums is

```
**df.corr().loc['ColA','ColB']**
```

we get matrix b/w both columns

Comment: maybe you should have tested your soln since the poster post a set of data and expected answer..  res = df[['Group', 'Age']].corr(). print(res)

Comment: it worked for me when i want to try on columns in df